# Is there a way to run Windows RGB mouse drivers on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, mouse, wine

I just got a new gaming mouse that is software programmable. The problem is that the software only runs on Windows and Mac. Not a big deal, I thought. I was able to use Wine and install the app but it just can't detect the mouse no matter what.

```
Mouse: GX Scorpion Spear Pro
Ubuntu: 22.10
Wine: wine-7.0 (Ubuntu 7.0~repack-8)
App: SmartGenius APP
```

Thanks in advance.

(EDIT): I added a screenshot of the app.[image: How it looks in the app]

Comment: Wine generally cannot support hardware apps so what you want is not likely to work

Comment: Would there be a workaround for this?

Comment: Probably not, so far as I can see

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: The only option is to look for replacement Linux software, e.g. using OpenRGB for the keyboard lights on my Asus G731 Laptop.